# In Visual studio 2013, how can I debug my require()-ed dojo modules?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, visual-studio-2013, dojo

Today, I moved all my javascript code into pure dojo modules, so I could build them and all the modules they use into a single dojo.js file to reduce my page requests from hundreds down to just a handful. This is a wonderful improvement in my code and I need to keep doing this.

BUT:

Since I'm calling my javascript libraries through require() now, I'm having a heck of a time figuring out how to debug them. I can't just place a breakpoint in the .js file anymore and expect it to be hit. The breakpoint is a little empty circle that says

```
"this breakpoint will not be hit, no symbols have been loaded for this document"
```

To illustrate what I mean, suppose you have a library file named library.js

```
//this is library.js
define(["dojo/query"], function(query){
function LibraryFuncA(a, b)
{
   return "" a + b;
}
return {LibraryFuncA: LibraryFuncA};
});
```

In my main cshtml file, I have to call it this way now:

```
<script>
require(["app/library"], function(lib){
     var help = lib.LibraryFuncA("how do I ", "debug this?");

});
</script>
```

Anyway, this require call will fetch the app/library module from the cache if its in the built dojo file or it will fetch it from the server if I'm using the normal dojo file. But if I wanted to set a breakpoint in library.js to see what was going on in the VS2013 debugger when using IE, how would I do it?

Is there a way I can call LibraryFuncA without using require when it's concealed in the anonymous function that way?

Comment: FWIW ideally Dojo shouldn't be using XHR to load normal modules - you should be setting `async: true` in your loader configuration if you're using the AMD API everywhere.  That will switch the loader to using script injection rather than XHR.  I'm not sure about VS2013 but most modern browsers should have no trouble being able to browse/debug code in modules loaded that way.

Comment: yes, i can debug in browser. But I really miss debugging in VS with internet explorer, it was handy.